# Object.entries() and Object.values() are not typed as arrays in WebStorm/PhpStorm

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, ecmascript-2017

I have TypeScript project with ES6 target, it uses `core-js` to polyfill ES2017 features and tsconfig.json is configured accordingly.

When `Object.entries(...)` and `Object.values(...)` are used, the results don't have array methods and properties (`map`, `forEach`, `length`, etc), they appear as plain objects to IDE, so `any[]` type should be casted explicitly:

[image]

While `Object.keys(...)` behaves like it should.

At the same time IDE somehow 'knows' about the proper types for `Object.entries` and `Object.values`, they are shown in accordance with TypeScript's `lib.es2017.object.d.ts` on Ctrl+Shift+P. But it seems to ignore the types for inspection, because overriding `ObjectConstructor` in current file solves the problem:

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    values(o: any): any[];
    entries(o: any): [string, any][];
}
```

`tsc` seems to be fine with the typings, so it looks like IDE-specific problem.

**This happens only when `Use TypeScript service` in `Languages & Frameworks > TypeScript` is unchecked.** Everything wents normal when TypeScript service is enabled (it is disabled intentionally because there were problems with TS service before).

Here is tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": [],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "es2017.object"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

What does this mean? Did my setup go wrong somewhere?

The problem persists with TypeScript 2.1.5 and latest IDE (EAP 2017.1).

Comment: definitely update to the latest TypeScript. The version you are using is over 1 year old

Comment: Well, the question is one year old, too. The problem disappeared for me at some point but I never figured out if this was due to TS or IDE update.

Comment: Awesome, that will teach me not to read properly. I'm very happy your issue got resolved, and I hope some day you'll find the answer to what was wrong. Until then, we are in the dark

Answer (score 2):

[Typescript 2.3 introduced new support for iterators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html) behind the `--downlevel-iteration` compiler flag, or by setting `.compilerOptions.downlevelIteration` to `true` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Note that this answer is the same as [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48585238/1068332) since it refers to the same compiler flag and similar symptoms, even though one refers to problems with a compiler and this one is about some IDE integration.

Answer (score 0):

go to your tsconfig.json and change the target, lib and module to es2017.